# Stuck with "Developer Rejected" and I cannot upload a new binary

Tags: ios, binary, app-store, updating

1. I uploaded a new app version. No problems.
2. I fixed a last minute bug.
3. I re-archived.
4. I rejected binary 1.
5. I pressed "Ready for upload new binary".
6. I uploaded the new version.
7. No problems.
8. 3 minutes later the new version was "rejected by developer" without me doing anything.
9. Now I cannot finish all steps in "Ready to upload new binary".

Screenshot of log and also "error" message. Which just says "can't save".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIZVh.jpg

I've emailed via the support but no response.

Anyone have a clue?

Comment: According to your screen shot, you had rejected two times.? right? Did you try after some time, which means after received error?

Comment: The second rejection (the latest) was not by me clicking "reject" as far as I remember. Unless I clicked it without realising it. I've tried several times over 1-2 days now.

Answer (score 1):

In step 4 (I rejected binary 1), make sure that the binary is actually removed by pressing the "red icon" that appears when you hover over the "build" link.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I can't verify if this was the solution as it was almost 5 years ago.